# LaTeX lstlisting - “\keywordsprefix” keywords are also emphasized in strings and comments

Tags: listings

I am trying to show some SAS code in a LaTeX document. To this end I want to use a customized lst-language. I have managed to implement everything but the user defined variables which start with an "&"-sign. Every word starting with "&" should be printed in bold and blue UNLESS it appears in a string or a comment. In my example it will be written in bold and blue all the time. Other keywords are not emphasized in strings or comments. Do you have any ideas why it doesn't behave as it should in my example? Any ideas how to fix my code?

Thanks in advance!

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{spYellow}{HTML}{ADAD00}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% SAS language definition

\lstdefinelanguage{SAS}{
  sensitive=false,
  alsoletter={\%\&},
  %
  % User variables
  keywordsprefix={\&},
  %
  % Comments
  morecomment=[f][\color{Green}\slshape][0]*,
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  %
  % Strings
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[d]',
  %
  % Datalines and cards
  morecomment=[s][\itshape\color{spYellow}]{datalines;}{;},
  morecomment=[s][\itshape\color{spYellow}]{cards;}{;},
  %
  % Distinct highlight for proc <proc>, data, run, quit
  morecomment=[s][\bfseries\color{DarkBlue}]{proc\ }{\ },
  morekeywords={keyword1},
  morekeywords=[2]{
    data ,proc ,run ,quit
  },
  %
  % Macros
  morekeywords=[3]{
    \%include ,\%let
  },
  %
  % Statements
  morekeywords=[4]{libname}
}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% SAS enhanced editor style

\providecommand{\textcolordummy}[2]{#2}
\lstalias{sas}{SAS}
\lstdefinestyle{sas-editor}{
  language          = SAS,
  showstringspaces  = false,   % Don't underline spaces in strings
  showspaces        = false,   % Don't underline spaces
  breaklines        = true,    % automatic line b\color{Blue}\color{Blue}reaking
  breakatwhitespace = true,    % breaks only at white space.
    basicstyle        = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    tabsize           = 4,      % Tab size
    lineskip          = 1.5pt,  % Sparing between lines of code
    numbers                     = left,
    commentstyle      = \color{black!50}\itshape \let\textcolor\textcolordummy,
  %
  % User variables
  keywordstyle = {\bfseries\color{NavyBlue}},
  %
  % Distinct highlight for proc <proc>, data, run, quit
  keywordstyle = [2]{\bfseries\color{DarkBlue}},
  %
  % Built-in macro functions
  keywordstyle = [3]{\color{Blue}},
  %
  % Statements
  keywordstyle = [4]{\color{Blue}},
  %
  % Strings and comments
  stringstyle  = \color{Purple},
  commentstyle = \color{Green}\slshape
}

\lstset{style=sas-editor}

\begin{document}

Text before the code.

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\begin{lstlisting}%[language=SAS]
/******************Macros************************/
/* Compile all macros   */
%include "&incodes.keyword1.makro1.sas";
%include '&incodes.keyword1.makro2.sas';
/*%include "&incodes.keyword1.makro3.sas";*/
/*%include &incodes.keyword1.makro4.sas;*/
%include &incodes.keyword1.makro5.sas;
\end{lstlisting}

Some text after the code.

\end{document}
```